# Better way of implementing message box and run in both windows and linux in python

Tags: python, linux, windows

I am implementing message box in python 2.7.9. I m writing code that should run in both Windows and Linux. **Below code works fine in windows, but not in Linux.** I know there is no module object of windll in Linux. Is there anything guidelines need to taken care to write a code which runs in windows and Linux environment? That would be great any documentation link for this. Thanks in advance.

```
import ctypes  # An included library with Python install.
ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0, "Your text", "Your title", 1)

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'windll'
```

Comment: Why not use a GUI framework (e.g. Tkinter, which is bundled with Python)?

Comment: @ Jonrshrpe Thanks. But I feel quite challenging to use GUI framework. ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0, "Your text", "Your title", 1)
Is there something similar to this.

Comment: It's not particularly challenging if all you want to do is pop up a message box!

Comment: I want to use custom exception handling as well. I m not much familiar with Tkinter to use with exception handler

Comment: Why do you think error handling with Tkinter would be different to handling errors in the rest of Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest option is probably to use a GUI framework; specifically Tkinter, which comes bundled with Python. The below code should work cross-platform (although Tkinter needs [a bit of extra installation work](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/) in Mac OS X) in Python 2.x and 3.x:

```
try:
    # Python 3.x imports
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import messagebox
except ImportError:
    # Fall back to 2.x
    import Tkinter as tk
    import tkMessageBox as messagebox

root = tk.Tk().withdraw()  # hide the root window

messagebox.showinfo('hello', 'world')  # show the messagebox
```

Result (in 2.7.10 or 3.5.0 on Windows 7):

[image: resulting messagebox on-screen]

There are other `messagebox` options, either to `ask...` (with various combinations of yes, no and cancel) or `show...` (error, warning or info).

Comment: Thanks. How do I do messagebox options, either to ask... (with various combinations of yes, no and cancel) or show... (error, warning or info).?

Answer (score 0):

Portability issues are usually solved by using an abstraction layer over the platform specific parts - an example being the `os.path` module in the stdlib, which has different implementations (one per platform) of the same API, and loads the right implementation at runtime.

Now when it comes to GUI, things get more complicated - specially on the unix world where there's no builtin gui toolkit, and quite a few possible choices. If you don't care about native look&feel and only need simple features then Tkinter is probably your best, else you'll have to look for a more complex crossplatform GUI toolkit (Qt comes to mind) or try to build and maintain your own abstraction level over "native" toolkits for the target platforms (which is mostly going to be a major PITA).